# Confusions in Holder's Inequality

Tags: inequality, holder-inequality

Holder's Inequality states that for nonnegative real numbers $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ we have $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^p\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)^q\ge \left(\sum_{i=1}\sqrt[p+q]{a_i^pb_i^q}\right)^{p+q}$$
Where $p$ and $q$ are positive real numbers.
Here is my problem : $a,b,c$ are positive reals, prove that $$(a^5-a^2+3)(b^5-b^2+3)(c^5-c^2+3)\ge (a+b+c)^3$$

But for $x>0$ we have $x^5-x^2+3\ge x^3+2$ so we only need to prove $$(a^3+2)(b^3+2)(c^3+2)\ge (a+b+c)^3$$
But when I read the solution, it says ''From Holder's Inequality, it follows ''  $$(a^3+2)(b^3+2)(c^3+2)\ge (a+b+c)^3$$

But I don't see that.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Could you write the second inequality more precisely? Perhaps write it without using the $$\prod$$?

Comment: @Deane Good enough?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be $a^5 - a^2 + 3$ etc. rather than $a^5 - a^2 + 2$ etc.

**Problem**: Let $a, b, c $ be positive reals. Prove that
$$(a^5-a^2+3)(b^5-b^2+3)(c^5-c^2+3)\ge (a+b+c)^3.$$

**Proof**: It is easy to prove that $x^5 - x^2 + 3 \ge x^3 + 2$ for all $x \ge 0$.

It suffices to prove that
$$(a^3+2)(b^3+2)(c^3+2)\ge (a+b+c)^3.$$

Using Holder's inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 (a^3+2)(b^3+2)(c^3+2)
 &= (a^3 + 1 + 1)(1 + b^3 + 1)(1 + 1 + c^3)\\
  &\ge (\sqrt[3]{a^3 \cdot 1 \cdot 1} + \sqrt[3]{1 \cdot b^3 \cdot 1} + \sqrt[3]{1\cdot 1 \cdot c^3})^3\\
  & = (a + b + c)^3.
\end{align*}

For Holder's inequality, see:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/H%C3%B6lder%27s_Inequality

Answer (score 0):

I would think Holder's inequality implies

$$(a^3+2)(b^3+2)(c^3+2)\geq \left((a^3b^3c^3)^{1/3}+ (2^3)^{1/3} \right)^3=(abc+2)^3$$

So it would be good to know how your last inequality follows from Holder's.